# What's wrong with my Spring MVC configuration?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I'm trying to setup and learn how to develop web applications with Spring MVC. I've been trying to follow a number of tutorials, but my application doesn't seem to want to work.

Enviro: Eclipse, m2e-wtp, spring, the whole shebang

Context root is BidApp.

I have one controller:

```
@Controller
public class AuctionController {    
    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {
        String message = "Hello World, Spring 3.0!";
        return new ModelAndView("hello", "message", message);
    }
}
```

My web.xml in WEB-INF:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
    <display-name>BidApp</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
         <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And my spring-servlet.xml also in WEB-INF

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Scans within the base package of the application for @Components to configure as beans -->
    <!-- @Controller, @Service, @Configuration, etc. -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.bidapp.controllers" />

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

My I start the application and navigate to `http://localhost:8080/BidApp/hello`, it gives me a 404. Are my xml files in the wrong place or am I missing some configuration parameter? Is there a good place I can look at all the available parameters for configuring a spring application. The spring framework reference, unless I'm reading it wrong, isn't helping.

Edit:

```
Tomcat logs:
Nov 18, 2012 10:07:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\php\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\runtime\win64;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\bin;C:\Users\Soto\Desktop\android-sdk-windows\tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Teleca Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Ruby193\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\SSH Communications Security\SSH Secure Shell;C:\Users\Soto\Desktop\android-sdk-windows\tools;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\Users\Soto\AppData\Roaming\npm\;C:\apache-maven-3.0.4\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin;;.
Nov 18, 2012 10:07:35 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:BidApp' did not find a matching property.
Nov 18, 2012 10:07:35 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Nov 18, 2012 10:07:35 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Nov 18, 2012 10:07:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 594 ms
Nov 18, 2012 10:07:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Nov 18, 2012 10:07:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.22
Nov 18, 2012 10:07:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext checkUnusualURLPattern
INFO: Suspicious url pattern: "*.*" in context [/BidApp] - see section SRV.11.2 of the Servlet specification
Nov 18, 2012 10:07:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
Nov 18, 2012 10:07:36 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization started
Nov 18, 2012 10:07:36 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Sun Nov 18 22:07:36 EST 2012]; root of context hierarchy
Nov 18, 2012 10:07:36 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]
Nov 18, 2012 10:07:36 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@6ad89088: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver#0]; root of factory hierarchy
Nov 18, 2012 10:07:37 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization completed in 739 ms
Nov 18, 2012 10:07:37 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Nov 18, 2012 10:07:37 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Nov 18, 2012 10:07:37 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1395 ms
```

Comment: Is there any error during the server startup?

Comment: Nope. It just doesn't show anything at the address shown above when I believe it should.

Comment: Do you have any server side logging? Also what is the package for your controller?

Comment: I've added the logs above. The controller is in `com.bidapp.controllers`.

Comment: Your url pattern matches anything dot anything, but Hello doesn't have any dot? What if you change your pattern to /*?

Comment: Can you please provide debug logs of your server.

Comment: Your url pattern matches anything dot anything, but "hello" doesn't have any dots. What if you change your pattern to /* ?

Comment: Sorry for the double post, my browser hang in the middle of its save.

Comment: If I change it to `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>`, I get `WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/BidApp/hello] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'`

Comment: what is the context path of the project?

Comment: It's in the 3rd line of my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use the url pattern like this

```
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
```

When you add `<mvc:annotation-driven />` to your config, it replaces the default set of handler mappings and handler adapters, and those defaults were the ones that handled the old-style controllers.

i think you should understand the difference between component-scan and annotation-config. If you use scan then you do not need to use config. 
[Difference between <context:annotation-config> vs <context:component-scan>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414794/difference-between-contextannotation-config-vs-contextcomponent-scan)

Please do execute with your old code with removing the `<mvc:annotation-driven />`

(In general)/ will be working even without mvcdefault servlethandler

Comment: <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>

Comment: @DarrylMiles Please consider the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405868/in-a-servlet-mapping-in-spring-mvc-how-do-i-map-the-root-of-a-url-pattern-direct then consider yourself for down voting if you have done that..

Comment: This was part of the issue, see below for what was missing.

Answer (score 2):

The dispatcher has an invalid mapping. Only 1 wildcard is accepted.

So change the dispatcher matching url to something like `/*`

So `/*.do` or `/*.htm` `*.html` but not `/*.jsp` as tomcat already maps the .jsps

If you want some REST urls, may I suggest using [UrlRewriteFilter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/)? It is really simple to use and can be used in closely the same way the apache rewrite filter is used.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the url-pattern to `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>` was not enough. In my spring-servlet.xml file I was missing a few elements:

```
<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->
<!-- This tag allows for mapping the DispatcherServlet to "/" (all extensions etc)-->
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>


<!-- Enables many annotations and searches for @Controller annotated methods etc.. -->
<context:annotation-config />
```

Once these were added, the appropriate Controller was found (based on annotations) and it was executed at the proper URI starting at `/`.

Comment: Please do execute with your old code with removing the <mvc:annotation-driven />